xskak / chessboard: White figures filled white at colored board
I find the color settings on xskak / chessboard to be quite complicated.
I have the board color style "brown/light brown" as far as I want it (but I'm not 100% sure whether I set it up correctly in the way the inventor intended).
I'm capable of either the colored chessboard or the colored pieces, but I can't do both at once.
I would like to change 2 things:

White figures filled with white (or creamy white); contours should remain black; and the fields should remain colored as they are.
Remove the hatching (pattern “north west lines”) on black (now brown) fields.

What do I have to do?

\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}

% How to fill the withe pieces with
\definecolor{mywhite}{HTML}{F1ECDA}% "cremewhite"
% ? 

\setchessboard{showmover=false, margin=false}

\storechessboardstyle{mystyle}{
% boardfontencoding=LSBC3, % ??
tinyboard,% board size
 pgfstyle=color,
 color=brown!88,% black fields
 trimtocolor=black,
 backboard,
 trimtocolor=white,
 color=brown!33,% white fields
 backboard,
setfontcolors,
}
\setchessboard{style=mystyle}% activate style globally

\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\chessboard[]
\end{document}


Well you want an encoding with piecemask and piece, and the board colors should be done in the pgf layer:
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage[LSBC5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessboard}

% How to fill the withe pieces with
\definecolor{mywhite}{HTML}{F1ECDA}% "cremewhite"
% ? 

\setchessboard{showmover=false, margin=false}

\storechessboardstyle{mystyle}{
 boardfontencoding=LSBC5, % ??
 tinyboard,% board size
 pgfstyle=color,
 color=brown!88,% black fields
 trimtocolor=black,
 backboard,
 trimtocolor=white,
 color=brown!33,% white fields
 backboard,
 whitepiecemaskcolor=mywhite,
 blackpiecemaskcolor=mywhite,
setfontcolors,
}
\setchessboard{style=mystyle}% activate style globally

\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\chessboard[]
\end{document}



OK.... TYVM.....

For my understanding: how was the hatch pattern removed?

by not using an encoding which uses the fieldmask.
